# How to get selected option value of all rows of table in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

I have an HTML table created with dynamically generated data with each row having different IDs. Each row contains 3 columns where 2 are text input fields and 1 is select field.

What I want to do is to get all content of each row of table but I'm unable to get selected option's value. I'm using a for loop to iterate through each column value of every row.

I'm getting correct values for the first two input fields but the select field is giving **undefined** value.

How to get the selected option value for each select field?

```js
function getData(){
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        var x = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].value;
        var y = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        var z = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].value; // select option field
        
    }
}
```

```html
<td><input value="first" id="first1" name="first[]" /></td>
<td><input value="second" id="second1" name="second[]" /></td>
<td>
  <select name="third[]" id="third1">
    <option value="option1">One</option>
    <option value="option2">Two</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: JavaScript uses zero-based indices; which means that the first cell is at index `0`, not `1`, and the last cell is at index `2`, not `3`.

Comment: `element.options[element.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks for pointing out, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select field appears to be the second child of the table cell and hence is accessed by `childNodes[1]`.

Demonstration of the first case:

```js
function getData(){
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var row;
    for (var i = 0,  row = table.rows[i]; i < table.rows.length ;i++) {
        console.log('here')
        var x = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].value;
        var y = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        var z = row.cells[2].childNodes[1].value; // select option field
        console.log(x,y,z)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td><input value="first" id="first1" name="first[]" /></td>
<td><input value="second" id="second1" name="second[]" /></td>
<td>
  <select name="third[]" id="third1">
    <option value="option1">One</option>
    <option value="option2">Two</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="getData()">Click</button>
```

The reason this happened was because you hadextra spaces between `<td>   <select>`. Remove them and it can be accessed with `childNodes[0]`

```js
function getData(){
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    
    var row;
    for (var i = 0,  row = table.rows[i]; i < table.rows.length ;i++) {
        var x = row.cells[0].childNodes[0].value;
        var y = row.cells[1].childNodes[0].value;
        var z = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].value; // select option field
        
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="dataTable">
<tr>
<td><input value="first" id="first1" name="first[]" /></td>
<td><input value="second" id="second1" name="second[]" /></td>
<td><select name="third[]" id="third1">
    <option value="option1">One</option>
    <option value="option2">Two</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="getData()">Click</button>
```

You also need to end you for loop and hence put a condition on number of rows